# How to save information in cookies using <a> element

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets

I am building 'Cart' page, I have list of items and  buttons, which should save that specific item in Cookie object.

Here is the code I have which prints items to webpage

```
    Cookie c;
                while(rs.next())
                {
                    out.println("<div id=\"aaa\">");
                    out.println("<div id=\"bbb\" style=\"background-image:url("+rs.getString("poster")+"); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size:cover;\">"+"</div>");
                        out.println("<div id=\"ccc\">");
                        out.println("<h2>"+rs.getString("name")+"</h2>");
                        out.println("<p>Category: <em>" + rs.getString("Category")+"</em></p>");
                        out.println("<p>Size: "+rs.getDouble("size")+"</p>");
                        out.println("<p>Publisher: "+rs.getString("publisher")+"</p>");
                        out.println("<p>Price:"+rs.getDouble("price")+"</p>");

                        c = new Cookie(rs.getString("name"), Double.toString(rs.getDouble("price")));
                        out.println("<footer class=\"align-center\">");
                        out.println("<a href=\"Cart\" target=\"_blank\" class=\"button alt\">Open</a>");
                        out.println("</footer>");
                    out.println("</div>");

                        out.println("<div id=\"ddd\"></div>");
                    out.println("</div>");
                    out.println("<hr />");
                }
```

what I want exactly is cookie object to be filled with item name and price after this button is pressed.

```
   out.println("<footer class=\"align-center\">");
                    out.println("<a href=\"Cart\" target=\"_blank\" class=\"button alt\">Open</a>");
                    out.println("</footer>");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can passed the value of specific product i.e `name,price etc` by passing that value in `<a href="">` and get that value in your `cart` page and use `request.getParameter("something")` to get value of that item passed and save in `cookies` like below :

```
 String name=rs.getString("name");
 String price=Double.toString(rs.getDouble("price"));
     out.println("<footer class=\"align-center\">");
   //passing value in url
     out.println("<a href=\"Cart?name="+name+"&price="+price\" target=\"_blank\" class=\"button alt\">Open</a>");
      out.println("</footer>");
```

And then in your `cart page` do like below :

```
 String name=request.getParameter("name");//getting value from url
 String price=request.getParameter("price");
Cookie ck=new Cookie("name",name);//creating cookie object name 
response.addCookie(ck);//adding cookie in the response
```

Also ,don't use `html`in your [servlet instead put this in jsp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101579/when-do-you-use-a-jsp-and-when-a-servlet)